# Django Middleware check if page contents was cached

Tags: django, middleware

I have a middleware that manages and denies access based on trial info stored in the user model.  One aspect of it is that it increments the request count by 1 each time.

But also on a lot of endpoints, we have the results returned cached using `method_decorator`.  Is there a way to see if the page they're accessing is cached or not, so that I can avoid incrementing their request count if they would be using a cached result?

Comment: how about redis, memcache, etc? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/cache/